# template backward compatibility with gcc 4.7

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc4, gcc4.7

Take the following code snippet:

```
struct whatever {};

template < template <typename, typename> class FOX, typename bat>
struct wulf {};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C = whatever>
struct box;

template <typename A, typename B>
struct box<A, B, whatever> {};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct box : wulf<box, C> {};

int main(void)
{
return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine under gcc 4.1.2, but yields the following error when compiling under gcc 4.7.2:

```
main.cpp:14:25 error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class,class> class FOX, class bat> struct wulf'
main.cpp:14:25 error: expected a template of type 'template<class, class> FOX', got 'template<class A, class B, class C> struct box'
```

This is the smallest example code snippet with which I seem to be able to reproduce this error and I don't know what is happening. Why is the code being rejected and is there a correct way of doing this which will compile under both?

Comment: That code should not have compiled in gcc 4.1 anyway... `box` is a template with 3 type arguments, which does not match the first argument of `wulf` that is a template with exactly 2 arguments. Template template arguments are in general tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `wulf` class template accepts, as its first template template-argument, a class template that takes two type parameters.

Here, you are trying to provide as a corresponding argument a class template (`box`) that takes *three* type parameters:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct box : wulf<box, C> {};
//                ^^^
```

This is illegal. It doesn't matter if a default type argument is specified for the third type parameter of the `box` class template: the type and number of template-arguments must match exactly.

To fix the problem, change the definition of your `wulf` class template as follows:

```
template < template <typename, typename, typename> class FOX, typename bat>
//                                       ^^^^^^^^
struct wulf {};
```

Here is a [*live example*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e1af1762d9bfe8cd72ac9c8f18ef2ba8-5b3ca54c063b84529bb3ccb6f730bb38) that shows your code compiling with the above fix.

Comment: That makes sense, like David pointed out above. What I'm curious about is why this seemed to compile alright with gcc 4.1

Comment: @PalaceChan: I would say it is a bug in gcc 4.1

Comment: @PalaceChan: Does this answer your question? :)

Answer (score 1):

Using C++11, you can solve the problem by changing `wulf` to:

```
template < template <typename...> class FOX, typename bat>
struct wulf {};
```

although GCC 4.1 won't accept it I'm afraid...

---

One more trick I sometimes use: Add a wrapper class for `box`:

```
struct whatever {};

template < template <typename,typename> class FOX, typename bat>
struct wulf {};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C = whatever>
struct box;

template <typename A, typename B>
struct box<A, B, whatever> {};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct box2 : box<A, B> {};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
struct box : wulf<box2, C> {};

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if this (loosing the third argument for `box` within `wulf`) is a problem in your case, but I had some use-cases in the past where this technique helped.

Comment: Yea I thought about this...but 4.1 won't take that

Comment: Ah thanks. Yes I think I'll post what I ended up doing when I find it (I can't right now)